# How to create a standalone program that automatically sends emails at a certain time?

Tags: c#, asp.net, database, email, .net-core

The situation is that I need to send an email notification to a group of people about the available jobs taken from database. The program needs to send an email everyday at 8am. My question is how do I start this, I need to use c# (either using .net or .net core, whichever is easier)and wondering what is the correct approach.

Comment: Write an app, which sends emails and schedule it in task scheduler.. but don't spam me.

Answer (score 3):

I highly recommend using Hangfire (https://www.hangfire.io/) for scheduling tasks.

The hangfire server, which processes the tasks, can run in ASP.NET Core or in a plain console application.

Comment: thanks for this advice, is there a tutorial or example where it takes data , not from ssms, but from toad database using .net core?